# My form won't submit, no errors are shown but the database will not store it

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

The form will just not submit. The values are not being stored in the database every time I enter them even though when I used the same code with different fields for my reservation page, it worked just fine. Please note this is a university assignment & we are just supposed to be able to show that the payment values are getting stored in the database.

The code is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Payment Page</title>
   <!-- custom css file link  -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="reservations.css">
</head>
<body>

   <!-- code for the menu bar & logo for the webpage-->
   <div class="banner">
      <div class="navbar">
         <a href="homepage.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="Homepage" style="width:150px;height:150px;"></a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="listings.php">Listings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>


<?php

if(isset($message)){
   foreach($message as $message){
      echo '<span class="message">'.$message.'</span>';
   }
}

?>

<div class="container">
   <h1> Make Payment </h1><br>
   <form action="payments.php" method= "POST">
    <label for ="t_id"> Tenant ID: </label><br><br>
    <input type = "number" name="t_id" required/><br><br>
    <label for = "Date_Paid">  Date: </label><br>
    <input type = "date" name="Date_Paid" required/><br><br>
    <label for = "Amount_Paid"> Amount: </label><br>
    <input type = "number" name="Amount_Paid" required/><br><br>
    <label for = "CC_Number"> Credit Card Number: </label><br>
    <input type = "number" name="CC_Number" required/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="payments" class="btn" value="Pay Now"><br><br>
</form>
</div>
</div>



<?php
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['payments'])) {

   $t_id = $_POST['t_id'];
   $Date_Paid = $_POST['Date_Paid'];
   $Amount_Paid = $_POST['Amount_Paid'];
   $CC_Number = $_POST['CC_Number'];
   
   
      $sql = "INSERT INTO payments(t_id, Date_Paid, Amount_Paid, CC_Number, Status)
      VALUES ('$t_id', '$Date_Paid', '$Amount_Paid', '$CC_Number','Pending')";

     if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $message[] = "Payment Made !";
        echo "Payment Made";
     } else {
        $message[] = "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . mysqli_error($conn);
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);
}
      

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The database name is rental and the table name is payments
[as you can check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thd7l.jpg)

The file name is payment.php
Please help me figure this out.

Comment: You don't dump your `$message`, so you don't know if it's really working or not.

Comment: It should absolutely be pointed out that you should **never** directly pass strings/values into your queries. This allows for things like SQL injection. Also, can you confirm that the form itself is not submitting, or is it submitting and not saving the values in the database?

Comment: It shows no error message when I press Submit but I get no "Payment Made" message, neither does it store in the database

Comment: It's probably failing, but the only thing you have in your else is `$message[] = "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . mysqli_error($conn);`, but then you don't do anything at all with `$message`.

Comment: It's worrying to see that you are how lax you are with regards to sql injection considering that your app is intending to log financial data and other personal information.